# Add items to object inside a function

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have the following javascript code/object:

```
    config = function(key) {
        props = {
            svgWidth: 500,
            svgHeight: 500,
            userUploadImgWidth: 1115,
            userUploadImgHeight: 528,
        };
        return props[key];
    }
```

I'd like to add to the `probs` object with additional key value pairs, creating something like this:

```
    config = function(key) {
        props = {
            svgWidth: 500,
            svgHeight: 500,
            userUploadImgWidth: 1115,
            userUploadImgHeight: 528,
            scaledDimensions: {
              scaleWidth: 500,
              scaleWidth: 232
            }
        };
        return props[key];
    }
```

I can seem to access the props object inside the function, it will return values using `config('userUploadImgWidth')` but I want to add new items to the object and just can't figure out the syntax.

Comment: `var props = { ... , userUploadImg: {width: 1115, height: 528}, ... }` Don't forget the `var` before `props`.

Comment: Is what you want not just what an object does out of the box? `config = { a: 1, b: 2}`. Add a property: `config.c = 3`. Read a property: `result  = config.c`, or to read it with a dynamic key name: `result = config[key]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a function out of that is utterly unnecessary. Are you sure you are not over-engineering something really trivial?

What's wrong with

```
config = {
    svgWidth: 500,
    svgHeight: 500,
    userUploadImgWidth: 1115,
    userUploadImgHeight: 528,
    scaledDimensions: {
        scaleWidth: 500,
        scaleWidth: 232
    }
}
```

and later.

```
something = config.userUploadImgWidth;
```